# View to image (in higher resolution)

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I've got a view which I want to store as an image (like taking a screenshot of it).
For this I use the following code:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.share_preview);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
view.draw(c);
```

And then I store the bitmap into the gallery.

The problem with that is, that the image that gets saved always has the same size as the view. Since the size of the view depends on the phones screen size the image has a different size on every device.

Is it possible to get an image of the view in a higher resolution (and same resolution on every device)?

What I've tried was to call scaleX() and scaleY() on the view before drawing onto the canvas. The view got scaled by that but the image still got the old size (I also changed the size of the bitmap).
The code then looked like this:

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.share_preview);


// here's the difference
view.setScaleX(2);
view.setScaleY(2);


Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
view.draw(c);
```

Maybe it takes to long until the scale got updated. But I don't know how to check when scaling finished (and also the scaled view should not be rendered because it looks totally wrong then).

Answer (score 5):

There is likely to be no absolute answer to such a question - you may appreciate that there are many steps involved in compositing the view hierarchy on a given device at any time, all of which are rendered to optimise their layout on a given device, alongside other system content such as side-bars, keyboards, toolbars and so-forth; all rendered under a specific screen resolution, pixel density and other display properties. I also note now, that any dynamic content such as text input, would be difficult to capture in this approach I outline.

What may get you quite a way towards a consistent, standardised "screen-shot" of the view that you control would be utilising a virtual display. [createVirtualDisplay](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html#createVirtualDisplay(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.Surface,%20android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay.Callback,%20android.os.Handler)) Set up the display w,h and dpi according to your needs. And provide a surface on which the content will be rendered.

```
mDisplayManager = (DisplayManager) getSystemService(Context.DISPLAY_SERVICE);

int flags = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PRESENTATION | 
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;

mVirtualDisplay =  mDisplayManager.createVirtualDisplay("MyVirtualDisplay", 
    WIDTH, HEIGHT, DENSITY_DPI, surface, flags);
```

The surface needs prompting into being drawn onto (there are various standard examples you could hook into, such as a Presentation), and inflate the same view layout that you are rendering on the device onto the virtual surface. You can pass the surface data to the bitmap in the end when you have recently rendered. See here for some help: [screenshot android presentation display/surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32163769/screenshot-android-presentation-display-surface)

More recently, as of API 24, [PixelCopy](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/PixelCopy) may help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your view inside ScrollView and HorizontalView.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sv"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/hsv"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/share_preview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!--CONTENT-->
        </FrameLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</ScrollView>
```

set the width and height of your view on Runtime to desired size.
Then instead of drawing bitmap from View, draw from HorizontalScrollView.

```
View view = findViewById(R.id.share_preview);
view.setLayoutParams(new HorizontalScrollView.LayoutParams(1600,900));
HorizontalScrollView hsv = findViewById(R.id.hsv);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(hsv.getWidth(), hsv.getHeight(), 
Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
hsv.draw(c);
```

Comment: then the image only contains the parts that are visible on the screen, since the view is too large for my screen it does not show the full view and the image is not completely

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to get the

```
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    view.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = shareContainer.getDrawingCache();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +File.separator+ "test.jpg");
    f.createNewFile();
    FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
    fo.close();
```

you can use "**Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false)**" for scaling the bitmap, but you can only reduce the size without any loss, if you try to scale up then the image will start turning blurry